# React Router/History Can't Resolve "history/createBrowserHistory"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I cloned my react project today and the project was working fine on my other mac. Then I started to face some problems with my router, especially the history.
The code in my `history.ts` is:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createHistory();
```

My `app.tsx`is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, Switch, } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import history from '../history';

const App = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
                    <Route path="/media" exact component={Media}/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/menu" exact component={Menu} auth={props.isSignedIn} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/create" exact component={PostCreate} auth={props.isSignedIn} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/delete/:id" exact component={PostDelete} auth={props.isSignedIn}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I tried to change my `history.ts` to:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

and no success, I also tried to change to

```
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from "history";
const history: History = createBrowserHistory();
export default history
```

And no success too, it's strange because my application was working fine months ago. I've searched all over Stack Overflow and no solution seems to fit. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? What is the issue? Can you validate the installed versions of `react-router`, `react-router-dom`, and `history` packages? From your project directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom history` and report back the installed versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, I noticed that the `createBrowserHistory.d.ts` weren't getting created. Probably because of my fault `yarn install`. I removed the project and re-cloned and installed the libraries using `npm`Then worked.